# How to make stacked bars with different gradients per dataset

Tags: chart.js

I change my charts from HighChart to chart.js and want to achieve a similar look
I have stacked bars and each bar should have an individual gradient like this
[Sample from highChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL7Vu.png)

But it seems that chart.js is doing the gradient to the complete bar not one the individual part of the stack

This is what I get from chart.js
[chart.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ7NZ.png)

sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<body>

<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d")
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Data",
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: function () { // Callback instead of static color
                    var gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 900);
                    gradientFill.addColorStop(0.0, '#003399');
                    gradientFill.addColorStop(1.0, '#F8F804');
                    return gradientFill;
                },
                borderWidth: 4,
                data: [100, 120, 150, 170, 180, 170, 160]
            },
                {
                    label: "Data",
                    fill: true,
                    backgroundColor: function () { // Callback instead of static color
                        var gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 900);
                        gradientFill.addColorStop(0.0, '#003399');
                        gradientFill.addColorStop(1.0, '#F8F804');
                        return gradientFill;
                    },
                    borderWidth: 4,
                    data: [110, 120, 150, 170, 180, 170, 160]
                }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    stacked: true,
                },
                x: {
                    stacked: true,
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone support me here, how to setup gradient to be different for each part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining the `backgroundColor` as a function, you are using
the [scriptable options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#scriptable-options)
feature of chart.js, that allows you to change the value of a property
depending on the context. This only make sense if the result of the
function is changing from dataset to dataset and, possibly, from bar to bar.
If the function always returns the same value, it is not necessary (a canvas gradient may be created before the chart was constructed).
The information about which dataset is processed and about the
bar for which the gradient is created is obtained from the *arguments*
provided by chart.js when it calls that function.

In particular, for the scriptable version of the `backgroundColor`,
the first argument, `context` has (among many others), the properties

- `datasetIndex` that identifies the dataset, and
- `dataIndex` which identifies the bar within the index.

You can use those two values to
set different gradients for different datasets, and to modify,
if needed, the gradients of individual bars.

The main difficulty is given by the fact that you have to set the
boundaries of the `LinearGradient` to the actual y boundaries of
each bar if you want that bar to have applied in full, with color stops
from 0 to 1. This is why the scriptable property makes sense, because you can use the sizes computed by chart.js
for each bar when you create the gradient.

Here's the code example, based on the code you posted. I factorised out
a unique `gradientBackground` function, that is called by all (both)
datasets `backgroundColor` properties.

```js
function gradientBackground(context){
    const {dataIndex, datasetIndex, element} = context;

    let {height, base} = element.getProps(["base", "height"], true);
    let ygTop, ygBottom;
    if(!height){
        const vScale = context.chart.getDatasetMeta(context.datasetIndex).vScale;
        const stacksY = context.parsed?._stacks?.y?._visualValues ?? [context.parsed.y];
        let yMax = stacksY[0], yMin = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < datasetIndex; i++){
            if(!Number.isFinite(stacksY[i + 1])){
                break;
            }
            yMin = yMax;
            yMax += stacksY[i + 1];
        }
        [ygTop, ygBottom] =  [yMax, yMin].map(vScale.getPixelForValue, vScale);
        if(!ygBottom){
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        // has to be adapted for horizontal bars and if value axis has reverse=true 
        ygTop = base - height;
        ygBottom = base;
    }

    const gradientFill = context.chart.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, ygBottom, 0, ygTop);

    // use datasetIndex to identify the dataset and dataIndex to identify the bar within the set
    // example setting
    if(datasetIndex === 0){
        gradientFill.addColorStop(0.0, '#003399');  // first dataset starts from blue
    }
    else{
        gradientFill.addColorStop(0.0, '#009933'); // second dataset starts from green
    }
    if(dataIndex === 5){
        gradientFill.addColorStop(1.0, '#F82F04'); // bars no 6 ends in red
    }
    else{
        gradientFill.addColorStop(1.0, '#F8F804'); // all other bars end in yellow
    }

    return gradientFill;
}
new Chart('myChart', {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Data 1",
            //fill: true,
            backgroundColor: gradientBackground,
            borderWidth: 4,
            data: [100, 120, 150, 170, 180, 170, 160]
        },
            {
                label: "Data 2",
                //fill: true,
                backgroundColor: gradientBackground,
                borderWidth: 4,
                data: [110, 120, 150, 170, 180, 170, 160]
            }]
    },
    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            }
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                stacked: true,
            },
            x: {
                stacked: true,
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get individual gradients for stacked bars by defining an array of gradient objects for each dataset.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d")
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Data 1",
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(0, 51, 153, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(0, 51, 153, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(0, 51, 153, 0.4)',
                    'rgba(0, 51, 153, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(0, 51, 153, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(0, 51, 153, 0.4)',
                    'rgba(0, 51, 153, 0.8)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [100, 120, 150, 170, 180, 170, 160]
            },
            {
                label: "Data 2",
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(248, 248, 4, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(248, 248, 4, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(248, 248, 4, 0.4)',
                    'rgba(248, 248, 4, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(248, 248, 4, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(248, 248, 4, 0.4)',
                    'rgba(248, 248, 4, 0.8)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [110, 120, 150, 170, 180, 170, 160]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    stacked: true,
                },
                x: {
                    stacked: true,
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not the solution,
one bar contains different "blocks" each of the block should have an individiual gradient
not on gradient for the whole bar

Answer (score 0):

According to provided code, to implement functionality, to setup gradient color to different parts of bar in stacked bar chart, using chartjs library, so that each part of bar has its individual gradient color, the following code can be checked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<body>

  <canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>

  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d")
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Data",
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: function(context) {
              const element = context.element;
              var gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 900);
              if (element && element.base && element.height) {
                gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, parseInt(element.base - element.height), 0, parseInt(element.base));
              }
              gradientFill.addColorStop(0.0, '#003399');
              gradientFill.addColorStop(1.0, '#F8F804');
              return gradientFill;
            },
            borderWidth: 4,
            data: [100, 120, 150, 170, 180, 170, 160]
          },
          {
            label: "Data",
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: function(context) {
              element = context.element;
              var gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 900);
              if (element && element.base && element.height) {
                gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, parseInt(element.base - element.height), 0, parseInt(element.base));
              }
              gradientFill.addColorStop(0.0, '#003399');
              gradientFill.addColorStop(1.0, '#F8F804');
              return gradientFill;
            },
            borderWidth: 4,
            data: [110, 120, 150, 170, 180, 170, 160]
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          position: "bottom"
        },
        scales: {
          y: {
            stacked: true,
          },
          x: {
            stacked: true,
          }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

It can be checked, if it works.